# Use jQuery to clean up HTML using DRY

Tags: jquery, html, dry

I'm trying to find out a good way to learn the DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself). I have a page with a lot of HTML in it. 90% of the HTML is repeated so I'm trying to find out how to clear that up.

On the page I have a few questions, all these questions have the same html code but differ in text. I have a jsFiddle with the project here http://jsfiddle.net/SBKyW/

```
    <div class="container_vragen">
        <p class="open_sub">&#x25BC; Heb je al je verplichtingen al geregeld?</p>
        <div class="antwoorden">
            <input id="ja" type="checkbox" value="ja" class="open_sub_ja"/><label for="ja">Ja</label>
            <input id="nee" type="checkbox" value="nee" class="open_sub_nee"/><label for="nee">Nee</label> 
            <div class="extra_info">?
                <div class="extra_info_popup">
                    Hidden tekst
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="submenu">
            <div>
                <p>Heb je DigiD?</p>
                <div class="antwoorden">
                    <input id="ja" type="checkbox" value="ja" class="sub_antwoord ja"/><label for="ja">Ja</label>
                    <input id="nee" type="checkbox" value="nee" class="sub_antwoord nee"/><label for="nee">Nee</label> 
                    <div class="extra_info">?
                        <div class="extra_info_popup">
                            Hidden tekst
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p>Heb je DigiD?</p>
                <div class="antwoorden">
                    <input id="ja" type="checkbox" value="ja" class="sub_antwoord ja"/><label for="ja">Ja</label>
                    <input id="nee" type="checkbox" value="nee" class="sub_antwoord nee"/><label for="nee">Nee</label> 
                    <div class="extra_info">?
                        <div class="extra_info_popup">
                            Hidden tekst
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p>Heb je DigiD?</p>
                <div class="antwoorden">
                    <input id="ja" type="checkbox" value="ja" class="sub_antwoord ja"/><label for="ja">Ja</label>
                    <input id="nee" type="checkbox" value="nee" class="sub_antwoord nee"/><label for="nee">Nee</label> 
                    <div class="extra_info">?
                        <div class="extra_info_popup">
                            Hidden tekst
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="akkoord"><br/>Akkoord</p>
            <div class="close_submenu">
                X
                <div class="close_okay">Deze vraag sluiten</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the html that is needed for one question. The structure is the same in every question but obviously the text is different.

What's the best approach to reduce my html code using jQuery?

Comment: Are you trying to learn DRY? Are you trying to achieve an actual goal (reducing the HTML)? These are two different approaches.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to reduce the html code in my website because it repeats itself a lot. I was hoping to do this with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

In certain situations using client-side templating (also called JavaScript templating) can be a good way to avoid repetitive HTML.

Basically, you can write one HTML "template" and apply it to as many objects as you'd like.

However, since the HTML would be generated when page loads, I'm pretty sure search engines will never see it. Maybe someone can correct me on this if I'm wrong?

Anyway, if you think this may be what you're looking for, there are many JS templating libraries out there. I personally use a slightly modified version of the extremely lightweight solution by John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Cheers

Comment: I think search engines would probably be able to see it. I've written lots of pages with dynamic HTML that is generated at runtime, and search engines don't seem to have a problem.
I guess they just load the page and then parse the HTML when it's finished loading, instead of only looking at the raw code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll check it out later tonight.

Comment: Thanks Surfitscrollit, I'll consider testing this at some point. If the engines really see it, I'd be using templating more.